how to use Shadow variable
For the convenience of calculation, I defined Cc as shadow variable and ComposeCc as the  genuine planning variable.
I want to achieve: when the planning variable of ComposeCc changes, all Cc associated with  the ComposeCc will also change. So I do the following steps:

ComposeCc contains a Cc list.
Define shadow variable Cc
Implement the update operation in SlotUpdatingVariableListener, that is, get the Cc list from ComposeCc and then update the value for Cc
Declare both ComposeCc and Cc as planning variables in PlanningSolution

Is my code correct? In addition, I have a question. In the variable listener, I update the Cc list from ComposeCc. I modify the value of Cc in the list. Will the variable value of Cc with the same id in the Solution also change?
// genuine variable.
@PlanningEntity
public class ComposeCc {
    @PlanningId
    private String id;

    // refer to ccList
    private List<Cc> ccList;

    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"slots"})
    private Timeslot slot;

    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "slots")
    private List<Timeslot> slotList;
}

// shadow variable
@PlanningEntity
public class Cc {

    
    @PlanningId
    private String id;

    private int IndexOfConsecutiveCcs;

    @CustomShadowVariable(variableListenerClass = SlotUpdatingVariableListener.class,
            sources = {@PlanningVariableReference(entityClass = ComposeCc.class, variableName = "slot")})
    private Timeslot slot;
}



@Slf4j
public class SlotUpdatingVariableListener implements VariableListener<ComposeCc> {
    @Override
    public void beforeVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, ComposeCc composeCc) {}

    @Override
    public void afterVariableChanged(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, ComposeCc composeCc) {
        updateSlotForCC(scoreDirector, composeCc);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityAdded(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, ComposeCc composeCc) {}

    @Override
    public void afterEntityAdded(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, ComposeCc  composeCc) {
        updateSlotForCC(scoreDirector, composeCc);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, ComposeCc composeCc) {}

    @Override
    public void afterEntityRemoved(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, ComposeCc composeCc) {}


    protected void updateSlotForCC(ScoreDirector scoreDirector, ComposeCc composeCc) {
        Timeslot slot = composeCc.getSlot();
        for (Cc cc : composeCc.getCcList()) {
            scoreDirector.beforeVariableChanged(cc, "slot");
            cc.setSlot(Timeslot.buildTimeslotFromOther(slot, cc.getIndexOfConsecutiveCcs()));
            scoreDirector.afterVariableChanged(cc, "slot");
        }
    }
}

@PlanningSolution
public class CourseSchedule {

    private String name;

    @ConstraintConfigurationProvider
    private CourseScheduleConstraintConfiguration constraintConfiguration;


    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Cc> ccList;

    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<ComposeCc> composeCCList;

    @PlanningScore
    private HardMediumSoftScore score;
}

